# jOOQ as a dependency in Scala 3 is broken?

Tags: scala, jvm, jooq

I am trying to use jOOQ as dependency in a Scala 3 codebase:

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.16.6")`

However when I try to do an import from this library -- like `import org.jooq.DSLContext` -- I get a compilation error.

The easiest way to reproduce this is using ammonite:

```
cs launch ammonite --scala 3.1.3
Loading...
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 2.5.4-11-4f5bf2aa (Scala 3.1.3 Java 11.0.15)
@ import $ivy.`org.jooq:jooq:3.16.6`, org.jooq.DSLContext 
Bad symbolic reference. A signature
refers to ApiStatus/T in package org.jetbrains.annotations which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling the signature.
Caught: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: failure to resolve inner class:
externalName = org.jetbrains.annotations.ApiStatus$Experimental,
outerName = org.jetbrains.annotations.ApiStatus,
innerName = Experimental
owner.fullName = org.jetbrains.annotations.ApiStatus
while parsing /Users/horta/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jooq/jooq/3.16.6/jooq-3.16.6.jar(org/jooq/Named.class) while parsing annotations in /Users/horta/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jooq/jooq/3.16.6/jooq-3.16.6.jar(org/jooq/Named.class)
Caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 740 while parsing annotations in /Users/horta/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jooq/jooq/3.16.6/jooq-3.16.6.jar(org/jooq/Named.class)
...
```

This is not the complete error, it gives the same type of error on a bunch of different classes, always related with this annotation `org.jetbrains.annotations.ApiStatus.Experimental`.

I've reproduced this using Java 11 and 18 (openjdk), using SBT and ammonite, with all versions of Scala 3.
When using Scala 2.13.* everything works correctly, we're using that in production.

Any idea what might be going on here? Any potential clues or possible workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in Scala 3 from version `3.2.0-RC1`.

See [reddit post in r/scala](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/vpxvg8/comment/iem8wz8/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).